# vim's syntax highlighting doesn't like "set -e # comment"

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vi

My vi / vim syntax-highlighting doesn't recognise the comment after the line "set -e". If the comment contains an unpaired apostrophe this messes up the rest of the file's highlighting.

[image: example]

What can I do to fix this? As shown having the comment in a new line avoids the issue, but I'd like a real fix. I'm new to vim, but eager to learn. Should it be reported somewhere as a bug?

Comment: What is the version of Vim and the `C:\Program Files\vim\vim73\syntax\sh.vim` file? In my Vim 7.3 / sh.vim version 114, `set -e` followed by a comment works fine.

Comment: vim is version 7.2.108, sh.vim is 102. Unfortunately I can't update vim to 7.3 and sh.vim is in a read-only (for me) directory, is there a  way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in your 7.2 version of the `syntax/sh.vim` script. You can download the latest version from the maintainer's web site at http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html ([direct download link](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/syntax/sh.vim.gz)), or grab it from the current Vim runtime: https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/runtime/syntax/sh.vim

When you cannot modify the original Vim installation, place the file in `~/.vim/syntax/sh.vim` (which is `...\vimfiles\syntax\sh.vim` on Windows). The user configuration overrides the system files. See `:help 'runtimepath'` for more details.

Now you're responsible for updating this file. So when the system upgrades to Vim 7.3 or later, don't forget to remove your user-copy to get the latest features!